# Error installing React from "getting started" tutorial

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I've tried install React Native from "[Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content)". When I run the command:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I got this error, and the application didn't lunch in the simulator.

```
~/tmp/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager ~
/Users/david/tmp/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/formatBanner.js:48
chalkFunction: (fn) => fn,
                    ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david/tmp/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/checkNodeVersion.js:12:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
~ Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

My system information:

Mac OS 10.11.6

node: stable 6.3.0 (bottled), HEAD

watchman: stable 4.6.0 (bottled), HEAD

XCode 7.3.1

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd installed node 6.3.0 from brew command. But the current node version was 0.12.7 I fixed this by doing the following:

1. brew uninstall node --force
2. brew install node
3. (optional, if you don't have nvm) brew install nvm
4. only if you have installed nvm from brew (step 3) you must **read the output brew command**
5. nvm install v6.3.0
6. nvm alias default 6.3.0

After that I was able to compile and run